# Add icon to GridViewColumnHeader

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview

I'd like to add an `icon` in my `GridViewColumnHeader` (WPF). It will display the direction of the sorting.

```
<GridViewColumn Width="140px" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LotDate}">
       <GridViewColumn.Header>
               <GridViewColumnHeader Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.OrderByDateCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}">DATE</GridViewColumnHeader>
       </GridViewColumn.Header>
</GridViewColumn>
```

I already find how to order, I just need the icon now ! Obviously, I will `binding` it after in my C#

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GridViewColumnHeader` is actually a `Button`.

So, you can provide any `Content` for it.

Eg;

```
<GridViewColumn.Header>
  <GridViewColumnHeader>
    <GridViewColumnHeader.Content>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image x:Name="SortIcon" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="25" Height="25" Source="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\MyIcon.jpg"/>
        <TextBlock Text="DATE"/>
      </StackPanel>
    </GridViewColumnHeader.Content>
  </GridViewColumnHeader>
</GridViewColumn.Header>
```

Now, you can simple set `Visibility` of `Image` control.

Comment: This is a part of the solution, but it doesn't correspond exactly. I've 4 `GridViewColumnHeader` which can be ordered. I would like to display the icon only on the ordered header. With this solution, do I have to create 4 styles ?

Comment: @DesTunK You can get fancy with this approach. You can make it re-usable, and so can get away with only one `Style`.

Comment: That's true. I hoped to have a bit more help, but this is the base of the solution. thanks

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks you !